# regex to match a substring, but not starting with certain characters

Tags: php, regex, perl

I am searching for a substring e.g. `test` , in a longer string e.g. `alongstringtest`.

In this example it would match ok

but I want to exclude certain cases ( when 'test' preceded by certain characters)

e.g.

> do not match 'a-test'   (because of '-' )
>
> do not match 'abcgtest'   (because of 'g' )
>
> do not match 'abc"test'   (because of '"' )

I haven't written any regex for a long time, so this has me pulling my hair out abit !

Comment: not sure why I've been marked down for asking a question, have i done something wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<![-g"])test
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is

```
/(?<![g"-])test/
```

But there is room for optimization if you need more performance. If `test` can't appear at the very start of the string, then the following is a clear winner in terms of simplicity and performance:

```
/[^g"-]test/
```

Otherwise, I'd try the following:

```
/test(?<![g"-].{4})/s

/^test|[^g"-]test/

/^test/ || /[^g"-]test/
```

Note: `-` can have special meaning in character classes, but not if it's the first character, the first character after the negating `^`, or the last character. I always use it last; it keeps things nice and simple.